# How do I rename a file after uploading it?

Tags: javascript

I have this input type, if I upload a file with less than 8 length add zeros, but what I need is to change my input with the new name.

```
<body>
<input type="file" id="upload" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#upload').change(function(e){
    var fileName = e.target.files[0].name; 
    var newName = fileName.substring(0,fileName.length-4);    
        while(newName.length<8){
            newName = "0"+newName;
        }
        console.log(e.target.files[0].name=newName);
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. I don't really understand your question. Could you please go into more detail about what you're trying to accomplish and what's not working for you. I did notice you have `name=newName` in a console.log. That's probably not where you want it. `name=newName` is assigning a value. Maybe that is intended but there is probably a better spot for it.

Comment: hi, what i want is that when i rename the file, it gets loaded into the input with the new name.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't change the name of a file on the client-side. You would need to rename the file from the server-side (with e.g. PHP)